# Flask: render_template multiple times within function?

Tags: python, flask

`render_template` in Flask only seems to work when it's done at the end of a function, eg `return render_template('index.html')`. I have a long function where I want to update a webpage several times to keep the user updated with the progress. Should this just be split into several functions with each one rendering a new page?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your question

Comment: There is a misconception in your thought. This responsibility is not from Flask, but from the front (browser). Take a look at Flask + AJAX examples.

Comment: it's more JS work.